# Excel duplicate data display corresponding column value

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have three columns (B,D,E) and I need to search the first column (B) and find duplicate values in a second column (D) and wherever that value resides eg:Let us say the function discovered cell B5 has the same string of text as D12 it will then look right next to D12 which is E12 and Display that value in G12.

Less wordy example a formula that will discover cell B5 and D12 are the same text and displays whatever is in E12 in G12

If more info is needed let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the duplicates are between column B and D, and not multiple duplicate values in column D, then try

```
=iferror(vlookup(B2,$D$2:$E$100,2,false),"")
```

The value in cell B2 will be looked up in D2:D100. If a match is found, the corresponding value from column E will be returned. If no match is found an error will be returned, but that will be suppressed by the Iferror function.

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,D:E,2,0),"") Worked for me which is what you suggested, but unlocking the rows and columns which is my fault I should of made it clear that I wanted to be able to drag it down and compare through a large dataset. Thanks teylyn!

Comment: You can use whole column references with Vlookup, or you can just change `$D$2:$E$100` to match your range. The $ signs make the reference absolute, so it will not change when copied down, whereas `B2` is a relative reference and will change to `B3`, `B4` etc, when copied down.